# Why are smart phones (mostly) refreshing the web page every few seconds?

Tags: logging, web

While looking at high traffic (supposedly) human visitors in my website's logs, I seem to be seeing a lot of page loads for what seem to be legitimate humans, using smart phones. The one that I'm looking at right now, refreshed the page every 4 to 8 seconds. Chrome 18 for Android 4.2.2  (Linux - Samsung). Sometimes it happens with desktops though. EG Chrome 33.0 on WinVisa on Verizon.net, from the same source that later uses an iPhone. This one likes to refresh every 4 seconds, but sometimes a longer cycle.

I've pretty well ruled out human clicking, it doesn't jive with the patterns. I can't think of anything about my site/server that would deliver pages so fast, in a sustained burst of fairly uniform delay lengths (often exactly four seconds apart). So I'm thinking certain browsers might be retrying loads. Anyone else seen this and figured what is going on?